# how to use Void type in a closure of protocol with associatedtype in Swift

Tags: swift, closures, swift-protocols

I've a little issue I cannot find an elegant way to use a closure with an associated type as a Void in a protocol.

Let's say I've the following protocol:

```swift
protocol MyProtocol {

  associatedtype OutputDataType
  associatedtype InputDataType

  var isCompleted: ( (InputDataType) -> OutputDataType)? { get set }
}
```

Now I've a class that conforms to this protocol with Void type inside the closure like this:

```swift
class MyClass: MyProtocol {
  var isCompleted: ( () -> Void )? // Error: Type 'MyClass' does not conform to protocol 'MyProtocol'
}
```

So I tried this:

```swift
var isCompleted: ( (Void) -> Void )? // warning: When calling this function in Swift 4 or later, you must pass a '()' tuple; did you mean for the input type to be '()'?
```

And ended up with this "weird" syntax:

```swift
var isCompleted: ( (()) -> Void )?
```

or this verbose one:

```swift
typealias InputDataType = Void
var isCompleted: ( (InputDataType) -> Void )?
```

But now when I want to assign this closure in an other class I need to explicitely use a "_" in parameter:

```swift
myClass.isCompleted = { _ in
// other code
}
```

Isn't possible to use something like this:

```swift
myClass.isCompleted = {
// other code
}
```

So do you know if it would be possible to get something more elegant like the example I quoted and expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've declared `isCompleted` as necessary via the protocol, you will have to implement it in `MyClass` and unfortunately use the "weird" syntax.

However, to make using it nicer, you can add an extension to the protocol for when `InputDataType == Void` that gives a convenience to accessing `isCompleted` without having to explicitly pass `Void`...  Something like this:

```swift
extension MyProtocol where InputDataType == Void {
    var isCompleted: (() -> OutputDataType)? {
        get {
            guard let isCompleted = self.isCompleted else { return nil }
            return { return isCompleted(()) }
        }
        set {
            if let newValue = newValue {
                self.isCompleted = { _ in return newValue() }
            } else {
                self.isCompleted = nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use the method on your class through the convenience, which gives you the last code example you were looking for:

```swift
var myClass = MyClass()
myClass.isCompleted = {
    print("Hello World!")
}
myClass.isCompleted?()
```